# How to make element fixed on scroll in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

This is a video of what I have so far https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tJMZfpe8hcqLcNMYiE-6pzwHX0eLofv1/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to make the "Available for 3 months" fixed once the contentOffset.y has reached the header. Similar to what a `position: sticky` in css would do.

So far, I thought of doing this via `onScroll` prop in the Scroll View Component but the issue is, I already have animations (Animated.Event) from the parent and child component in place, meaning the only way for me to do this would be via the `listener` function in the `Animated.Event` but doing that, leads to a super choppy animation if the `useNativeDriver` option is set to false.

If I set that to true, the whole thing won't work (it crashes). The error is along the lines "onScroll is not a function, it's an instance of Animated.event"

So, Say we have two components, the parent is `Parent.js` and the child (a scroll view) is `ChildScrollView.js`

The `ChildScrollView.js` already has animations on the scroll view, but we need to add some more in the `Parent.js` component, to do with Navigation which the `ChildScrollView.js` can't handle

So it's coded like this:

`Parent.js`

```js
componentWillMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    const { scrollY } = this.state

    const bgColor = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [HEADER_HEIGHT / 4, HEADER_HEIGHT / 2],
      outputRange: ['transparent', 'rgb(255,255,255)'],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    })

    const titleColor = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_HEIGHT / 2],
      outputRange: ['transparent', colors.paragraphs],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    })

    const titleMarginTop = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_HEIGHT / 2],
      outputRange: [HEADER_HEIGHT, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    })

    navigation.setParams({
      bgColor,
      titleColor,
      titleMarginTop,
    })
}

onScroll() {
}

render() {

  return (
    <ChildScrollView
      {...childProps}
      onScroll={Animated.event([
        { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } },
      ], {
        useNativeDriver: false, // when I do this, it become super laggy, but setting it to true makes the app crash
        listener: this.onScroll,
      })}
    >
      <MakeMeFixedOnScroll>I could do this in css with "position: sticky"</MakeMeFixedOnScroll>
    </ChildScrollView>
  )
}
```

And the child is similar,

```js
<Animated.ScrollView
 {...props}
 onScroll={Animated.event(
   [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
            {
              useNativeDriver: false,
              listener: event => {
                if (onScroll) onScroll(event)
              },
            }
          )}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
```

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e) might offer some help :)

Comment: @VilleKoo Thanks for that, I've already done what was set up in that article pretty much. The issue is I need to add an animation that does not rely on the Animated.Value() but on the contentOffset. The only way to do this is by adding a "listener" function, but when I do that - enabling the "useNativeDriver" leads to an error [onScroll is not a function, it's an instance of Animated.event]. Without it, the animation is way too laggy

Comment: Hi @StephenJesse , I've encountered the same situation. Do you have any updates or solution on this?I'd be very happy if you can help me

Comment: @marwin sorry I haven't been active on this site for a while, what I ended up doing was just adding a listener to the scroll Y value. Once it reached a certain position, which I calculated by adding the frame heights of the image, title etc, I set the position of the banner to fixed, and the top, left, right insets to 0. Did the same thing in reverse scroll. Probably not a good solution, I'd imagine now you could something a lot cleaner possibly using React native re-animated but I ended up abandoning that project and I haven't gone back to it since. I can send you the code if you want?

Comment: @StephenJesse Thanks so much for the response Stephen. I've tried to use that same methodology, but in the end, it;s not as smooth as I expected. Yes, thank you so much. I'd love to have some look at your code

Answer (score 0):

I would use SectionList

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) => (
    <Text style={styles[item.type]}>{item.text}</Text>
  )}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
    title && <Text style={styles.sticky}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  sections={[
   { title: null, data: [{
       type: 'heading', text: '133 Random Road'
     }, {
       type: 'heading', text: 'Donnybrook'
     }, {
       type: 'subtitle', text: 'Dublin 4'
     }, {
       type: 'title', text: 'From E1000/month'
     }]
   },
   { title: 'Available For 3 Month', data: [{
       type: 'text', text: 'Beautiful for bedroom...'
     }]
   }
  ]}
  stickySectionHeadersEnabled
/>
```

Comment: I actually managed to accomplish it by adding a listener to the "Animated.Value". I need to do some testing, however, to make sure that it works on all devices. Tested on my iPhone XS Max.

Comment: You sure it will probably work on android? Not Over-engineering is important

Comment: That's a fair point. I don't know how well a section list would work with the whole Parralax Header that I have set up already